# Set colour of equations when using preview package

Tags: equations, color, preview

I use the preview package to export a pdf containing only my equations by putting the following in the preamble

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage,displaymath,textmath]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{equation*}
\makeatletter\renewcommand\@eqnnum{}\makeatother
```

I would like to set the colour of the exported equations. How can I specify the colour such that the preview package will see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear what specific document class you are using, but I am able to get (for example) red equations by using the `color` package and setting the color within the `equation` environment.

`\ifPreview` can be used as shown to turn coloring off when not in preview mode.  The package should be disabled by removing the `active` option to `\usepackage` so as to keep `\ifPreview` defined (as opposed to disabling the entire package, which would break things).

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[active,tightpage,displaymath,textmath]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{equation*}
\makeatletter\renewcommand\@eqnnum{}\makeatother

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
\ifPreview\color{red}\fi
a^2 + b^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi r^3}}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Gives previews as:

[image: preview eq]

But when disabled, appears as:

[image: regular eq]

Comment: `\ifPreview` works well. To avoid rewriting all my equations and because I'm actually using Lyx, I put this in the preamble
`\ifPreview\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{red}}\fi`
I suspect if may be incorrect/fragile but seems to work for me.